# How many words can we build using exactly 5 A's, 5 B's and 5 C's

Tags: combinatorics

How many words can we build using exactly 5 A's, 5 B's and 5 C's if the first 5 letters cannot be A's, the second 5 letters cannot be B's and the third 5 letters cannot be C's? 
Hint: Group the different ways according to the number of B's in the first group.

Comment: Having a bit of trouble thought the answer was 8064 but I was wrong

Comment: The title of your question is confusing. In the body you add essential extra conditions. That should at least be mentioned in the title.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, but can u just give me the answer please

Answer (score 6):

Split up in words $w_1$, $w_2$ and $w_3$ consisting each of $5$ letters. The final word of $15$ letters is concatenation $w_1w_2w_3$.

Let $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ denote the number of letters $B$ that are used in $w_1$. 
Then there are $5-k$ letters $C$ in $w_1$.

The remaining $k$ letters $C$ must be used in $w_2$. Next to them $5-k$ letters $A$ must be used in $w_2$.

Finally $5-k$ letters $B$ and $k$ letters $A$ remain to be used in $w_3$.

For $w_1$ (and also for $w_2$ and $w_3$) there are $\binom5{k}$ possibilities so for the whole word there are $\binom5{k}^3$ possibilities.

So the final answer is:$$\sum_{k=0}^5\binom5{k}^3$$

Comment: @ByronSchmuland have you got any other solution i could work with?

Comment: This is a neat mathematical solution (+1). I have added an answer just as a colorful explanation.

Comment: @Gabzmann Sure, there is a more complicated solution using inclusion-exclusion and rook polynomials. But drhab's solution is much better for this problem.

Comment: @trueblueanil thanks very much got the answer!

Comment: @Gabzmann: You're welcome !

Answer (score 4):

A picture is said to be worth a thousand words, so here is a colorful intuitive explanation.

Start with

$\color{red}{B B B BB}||\color{green}{ C C C C C}||\color{blue}{A A  A A A}$, then

$\color{red}{B B B B}\color{green}{ C||C C C C}\color{blue}{A|| A  A A A}\color{red}{B}$ , then

$\color{red}{B B B}\color{green}{ C C || C C C}\color{blue}{A A || A A A}\color{red}{B B}$, etc

Notice the symmetry involved, and that you move from one to the next by simply shifting letters by one to the left (in a circle)

Can you compute $\binom{5}{0}^3 + \binom{5}{1})^3 + ..... + \binom{5}{5}^3$

Comment: +1 Nice! Indeed, visualisation is very helpful in mathematics.